# Swift: ! instead of = nil

Tags: swift

I've recently taken up Swift in order to learn how to program iOS apps. I've been following Skip Wilson's tutorials and there's a moment when he connects an outlet and gets:

```
@IBOutlet var ticTacImg1: UIImageView = nil
```

instead of getting that I obtain:

```
@IBOutlet var ticTacImg1: UIImageView!
```

if I try to change it Xcode tells me it's an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In early versions of Xcode 6, anything marked as `@IBOutlet` was turned into a weak implicitly unwrapped optional.

That is

```
@IBOutlet var ticTacImg1: UIImageView = nil
```

would be compiled as

```
@IBOutlet weak var ticTacImg1: UIImageView! = nil
```

**This is no longer true.** Now you must declare its optional status, but it will still be weak.

That is

```
@IBOutlet var ticTacImg1: UIImageView! = nil
```

would be compiled as

```
@IBOutlet weak var ticTacImg1: UIImageView! = nil
```

---

The reason why `ticTacImg1` is not initialized to `nil` is that it doesn't matter. In Swift, implicitly unwrapped optionals which are not initialized have the value `nil`, so `= nil` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

`@IBOutlet var ticTacImg1: UIImageView!` is the correct code.

An `@IBOutlet` property needs to be optional because it initially has a `nil` value before the system connects the view to it. Marking it as an implicitly unwrapped optional with `!` means that it will be unwrapped automatically whenever it is used.

I'm not sure which specific tutorial you're referencing, but my initial thought is that he could be using an early beta of Xcode 6 that didn't enforce this.

Comment: And crash if it is a nil.

Comment: @Abizern Correct, but in most cases a variable connected to the Storyboard will never be nil after initialization.